# Javascript checkboxes with the same class name

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I would like to do when I check one checkbox the other checkboxes get disabled not the checked checkbox.

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkbox");

function check() {

    if (checkbox.checked) {
    checkbox.disabled = "true"
} 

}
```

```html
 <input onclick="check()" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input onclick="check()" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
   <input onclick="check()" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <input onclick="check()" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

Answer (score 1):

`document.querySelector(".checkbox")` finds the first element with the class checkbox, so if you have multiple checkbox inputs it'll only ever affect the first one.

One way around it is to pass a reference to which checkbox you're calling it with (with the `this` keyword):

```js
const boxes = document.querySelectorAll(".checkbox")

function check(checkbox) {
  for (const box of boxes) {
    if (checkbox.checked && (box !== checkbox)) {
      box.disabled = true
    } else {
      box.disabled = false
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
<input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```

The `<input>`s pass themselves as parameters to the function so you can individually control them. If you iterate over every `.checkbox`, you can check:

- Is the selected box checked
- Is the selected box the one I'm currently on in the iteration

Answer (score 1):

Is this what u want?

```js
let checkbox = document.querySelector(".checkbox");

function check(variable) {

//Amount of elms with .checkbox class (4 checkboxes)
var c_len = document.querySelectorAll( '.checkbox').length;

//Turn off all checkboxes
for (i = 0; i < c_len; i++) {
document.getElementsByClassName("checkbox")[i].checked = false;
}

//Turn on the only one that was actually clicked..
 variable.checked = "true"

}
```

```html
<input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
  <input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
   <input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
    <input onclick="check(this)" class="checkbox" type="checkbox">
```